# How detect if i'm moving mouse to left, right, top or bottom inside TImage component on mousemove event?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, onmousemove, timage

I want know how detect to what side i'm moving mouse: to left, right, top, bottom inside TImage component on `mousemove` event?

Thank you.

Comment: What is stopping you working it out by recording tthe previous mouse coordinates and then calculating the change yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example to be used in an `FMX` project. For a `VCL` project, you would use integer variables.

First, declare two variables `Xold, Yold: single;` for example in the private section of the form.

```
private
  Xold, Yold: Single;
```

Initialize these variables e.g. in the forms `OnCreate()` event. Using `NaN` requires `System.Math` in the uses clause.

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Xold := NaN;
  Yold := NaN;
end;
```

Then, in the `OnMouseMove()` event, calculate the movement horizontally and vertically, negative value indicate moving left or up, positive right or down.

```
procedure TForm5.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
var
  horz, vert: Single;
begin
  if not IsNan(Xold) then horz := X - Xold else horz := 0;
  if not IsNan(Yold) then vert := Y - Yold else vert := 0;
  Xold := X; // save new values
  Yold := Y; //
  // use horz and vert as needed
  Label1.Text := Format('h: %f, v: %f',[horz, vert]);
end;
```

You may also want to reset the `Xold` and `Yold` variables to `NaN` when the mouse leaves the image.

```
procedure TForm5.Image1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Xold := NaN;
  Yold := NaN;
end;
```

It was asked in comments, why initialize to `NaN` instead of just zero? `Xold := 0; Yold := 0` is the top-left corner. If the mouse entry to the image happens at e.g. right side, the first move would be a jump from 0 to image width. Using `NaN` we can omit the first entry as a move and just store the entry point in `Xold` and `Yold` for use with next move.

Comment: thank you, but i need obtain the four sides separately. In your example, you get 2 sides (for example right and down) in only one moviment. I need for example: i move the mouse to top, then `Label1.Caption := 'you moved mouse to top`

Comment: Oh then just apply some simple rules, this is what I meant with *use horz and vert as needed*: `if vert < 0 then label1.text := 'you are moving to top side' else if vert > 0 then label1.text := 'you are moving to bottom side' else if horz < 0 then label1.text := 'you are moving to left side' else if horz > 0 then label1.text := 'you are moving to right side'`

Comment: I just need to ask why the Nan I mean you could've just initialized them with zero in the first place

Comment: @Nas To be able to distinguish from valid values at the entry to the `TImage`, zero would indicate top left corner, what if entry happens at bottom left. Thanks for asking though, I just realized, the values should be set back to Nan at exit from the image.

Comment: Oh I did not see that case. Thank you for this I learnt something +1